# How to find number of lines in an image using hough transform?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I'm not able to get the exact number of lines that are present in the image using hough transform.

I've found the houghLines for the image and now when printing the number of lines using the hough lines mapped image i'm not able to get the exact number of lines.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img=cv2.imread('lines.png')

edges=cv2.Canny(img,0,150)


lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 2, 1*np.pi/180, 45, minLineLength=1, maxLineGap=1)



for line in lines:
  x1,y1,x2,y2=line[0]
  cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2) 


plt.imshow(img)
print(len(lines))
```

The expected output is 5, but actual output is 7 from the following image:

[image: input image]

Comment: Just threshold the image and use blobs and connected components to count all the black regions.

Comment: I wanted to use only houghlines. using the output of the houghlines I need to get the result. Is it possible???

Comment: You cannot count from simply hough lines. You need to either get contours or blobs and count those.

Comment: can you do it for the above image and show it in practical??

Comment: See the code below by nathancy

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `cv2.HoughLinesP()`, a much simpler approach is to threshold and find contours. When iterating through `cv2.findContours()`, you can keep track of the number of lines with a counter. If you insist on using `cv2.HoughLinesP()`, you could play with the *minLineLength* and *maxLineGap* parameters to correctly detect the desired lines

---

Threshold

[image]

Detected lines

[image]

Result

> 5

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

lines = 0
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 3)
    lines += 1

print(lines)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: If I give an image with a circle and a line and ask to count the number of lines the output should be 1 but in your case I would be 2.

Comment: In your original image, there are only lines, so this method works for images that have only lines. If you have other shapes in the image, you can look into other methods such as aspect ratio to filter out shapes. Image processing techniques vary based on image to image, there is no one fit all solution to all images

Answer (score 0):

*print(len(lines))* that you are using gives you the exact number of lines detected by hough transform. In your case, the number is 7 (instead of 5) because hough transform can find 3 lines in the neighboring pixels that are very close to each other which makes it looks like one (long) line.

In order to find the difference:

Either plot each line in different color then you know the difference between them

Or plot the x,y co-ordinates for each line, you know how close they are.

If you want lesser lines then you need higher *minLineLength* or *minimum thershold* values in the *HoughLinesP* function.

Hope it helps!